# git fetch only specific subets of tags

Tags: git, github

Does it possible to fetch only specific subets of tags?

I'm trying below command without success

```
git fetch origin refs/tags/<prefix>*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with a little work. Use `git ls-remote --tags origin` to get the tags. Cut off just the tag name. Search for your desired tags. And pass that list into `git fetch`.

```
git ls-remote --tags origin | cut -f2 | grep 'refs/tags/<prefix>' | xargs git fetch origin
```

Comment: the command works as expected when running it from my desktop. however, when I try to  run it from a bash script inside a step in Jenkins it brings the entire tags. How come Jenkins interpertates it differently?

Comment: @NZL I can only guess that nothing is being passed along to `git fetch origin`. Check what the output of `git ls-remote --tags origin | cut -f2 | grep 'refs/tags/<prefix>'` is.

Comment: This sometimes fails with `fatal: invalid refspec '<tag-name>^{}'`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit non obvious but you can achieve this using [refspecs](https://git-scm.com/docs/pull-fetch-param#Documentation/pull-fetch-param.txt-ltrefspecgt). The simple scenario is using a singular *tag refspec*, say all tags matching `v2.9*` from the git projects.

```bash
git fetch origin '+refs/tags/v2.9*:refs/tags/v2.9*' --no-tags
```

Note the confusing `--no-tags`, which really means "don't do tag following". It's not related to the `--tags` flag. See discussion on the [mailing-list](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqlepjivv4.fsf@gitster.g/).

More advanced patterns can be constructed using a *tag refpec* (`+`) for all tags with one or more *negative refspecs* (`^`) to exclude tags matching a pattern.

```bash
git fetch origin '+refs/tags/*:+refs/tags/*' '^refs/tags/foo*' '^refs/tags/*biz'
```

This will fetch all tags (`*`) excluding tags starting with `foo` or ending with `biz`.

You should also be able to omit `+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` and using `--tags` instead (I think that's what it does).

```bash
git fetch origin --tags '^refs/tags/foo*' '^refs/tags/*biz'
```

You can also configure fetch to use such rules by default, see [this thread](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqlepjivv4.fsf@gitster.g/) on the mailing-list.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `git fetch origin 'refs/tags/foo/*:refs/tags/foo/*` should only fetch `foo/*` tags, but it fetches _all tags_ for me. This is puzzling. Using `git 2.38.1`

Comment: @jakub.g no, it's a bit more convoluted. It doesn't fetch *all* tags, it fetches all `foo*` tags **as well as** all tags it can find by "following" the references fetched. This is the default and it's overridden using `--no-tags`. Note that it would only fetch `foo*` if no other tags were reachable or already fetched

Answer (score 0):

This is weird, but here's what worked for me to only fetch `foo/*` tags:

```
git fetch origin --no-tags 'refs/tags/foo/*:refs/tags/foo/*'
```

The `--no-tags` is important. Without it, it would fetch *all* tags.

Comment: Check the [conversation](https://public-inbox.org/git/xmqqlepjivv4.fsf@gitster.g/) on the mailing-list for an explanation of `--tags` and `--no-tags`

Comment: The gist is that it's a weird name for a flag that should have another name like `--no-follow-tags`